# Step sensor listener doesn't receive real steps number

Tags: android, android-sensors

I have a simple app that listens for steps. I use STEP COUNTER sensor for that purpose. But results are horrible. For example

```
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    stepCounter = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, stepCounter, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI,(int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMicros(10));
```

is detecting only 10 - 30 % of steps. And it doesn't depend on latency or batching.  Results on Samsung S9 are even worse. 
I tried to use Activity context, hoping to improve results but it didn't help.
Does someone have ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944114/sensor-stepcounter-sometime-not-work-well-on-samsung-device

Comment: Step detector shows the same behavior